# In Arkham Horror, if a monster surge exceeds the max allowable monsters, does the monster that caused the max to be exceeded get discarded?

Tags: arkham-horror

If I the outskirts is already at maximum capacity, and I have to add 5 more monsters because of a monster surge, do I empty the Outskirts and then add 4 monsters? More specifically, does the monster that put the outskirts "over the edge" get discarded (the alternative being he gets carried over to the next group of outskirts monsters)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. See this example from the [official Arkham FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf), p.12 (emphasis mine):

> In a 3-player game, the  monster limit is 6  and  the  maximum number
>   of monsters in the Outskirts is  5. There are 3 open gates on the
>   board, 6 monsters in  Arkham, and 4 monsters in the Outskirts. During
>   the  Mythos Phase, you draw a location that already has  an open gate,
>   so you have to draw 3 more monsters.  You would first draw 2 monsters
>   and place them in the  Outskirts. The Outskirts limit would be 
>   exceeded  upon  placing the second monster, so you would then increase
>   the terror level by 1 and return the six monsters in the  Outskirts to
>   the cup. **Finally, you would draw the third  monster and place it in
>   the Outskirts**.

Comment: I realize now that I worded the question badly. I was actually asking whether the monster that makes the outskirts exceed the maximum allowed is then carried over to the outskirts after emptying it or whether the monster that tips the scales is sent away. I see from your quote that it is sent away. I'll look to clarify the question so people see this distinction from the question.